# Why does the displayed Google Drive quota not match my local disc usage?

Tags: google-drive

Google Drive has been telling me I am using close to 15 / 15 GB of the free plan. However, when I check my local Google Drive folder on my computer, the files seem to total actually only about half of that. Is there something I am missing, or is Google displaying wrong information? (Possible in order to make me upgrade to a paid plan?)

This is the quota distribution given on http://drive.google.com :
[image]

Then here is the Mac desktop app's quota display:
[image]

But when I use the `du` command in terminal, the last line (total) is reading something vastly different:
[image]

Also, I've not recently been shifting big files, so this is not a issue about Google's displayed number "pending recalculation". Am I missing something completely obvious, or is this indeed a bit fishy?

Comment: Items in Trash will count against your quota, but I don't believe it'll be on your local drive.

Comment: So you are saying there is some kind of hidden "trash" on google drive (online version)? If so, where would I see those files in "trash"?

Comment: "Hidden"? Not at all. It should be pretty obvious. Check the menu on the left.

Comment: Oh wow. I have never noticed that menu item. Presumably, the trash will get emptied as I hit my quota ceiling, thus keeping me at just under 15GB as long as there is trash items to remove?

Comment: From what I recall, items are removed from the trash every 30 days. You can, of course, clear it out earlier.

Comment: This was it. It took over night to update the displayed usage quota, but emptying the "bin" was what had hogged all the quota. Also, there seemed to be year-old items in there. If you want to answer, I'll accept this hint ;) Maybe I'm not the first not last to wonder about this.

Comment: This is a duplicate, so better to upvote the answer(s) at the duplicated question.

Comment: Oh great, thanks for linking. I did quite a bit of search before posting, but somehow that one didn't come up. I'll upvote.